# Wie kann man im Geschäft einem Verkäufer korrekt sagen, dass man sich zuerst nur umschauen möchte und noch keine Hilfe braucht?

Tags: word-usage, expression, grammaticality, speaking

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
> *[Natural way to deny help from a shopkeeper](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17941)*

Wenn man in ein Geschäft geht und sich zuerst nur umschauen möchte, aber ein Verkäufer kommt und fragt z.B. »Womit kann ich helfen?«, wie kann man korrekt antworten, dass man sich zuerst nur umschauen möchte und noch keine Hilfe braucht?

Ich habe nach einer Antwort gesucht, aber bin noch nicht sicher, ob die von mir gefundenen Optionen richtig sind. Könnt ihr bitte bestätigen, ob diese Antworten in solcher Situation richtig sein werden und falls nein, könnt ihr bitte andere Antworten vorschlagen?

1. > Ich möchte mich zuerst umschauen und wenn ich Hilfe brauchen werde, dann ich werde mich bei Ihnen melden.
2. (in einem Geschäft mit Kleidern (auf Eng.: clothes))

   > Ich möchte mir die Kleider zuerst anschauen und falls ich Ihre Hilfe brauchen werde, dann ich werde mich bei Ihnen melden.
3. (im beliebigen Geschäft)

   > Ich möchte mir die Waren zuerst anschauen und falls ich Ihre Hilfe brauchen werde, dann ich werde mich bei Ihnen melden.

Habt ihr andere/bessere Vorschläge?

Comment: `... *Ihre Hilfe brauchen werde, dann* ...` sounds strange to me, I would just say  `... *Ihre Hilfe brauche, dann*...`. Actually I'd be **way** ruder than that, I'd just say "Thanks, just looking" or rather "Danke, ich schaue erst mal"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich verwende für gewöhnlich nur:

> Ich schaue mich erst mal um.

Oder, höflicher:

> Ich würde mich gern erst einmal umschauen.

Ohne weitere Zusätze.
Insbesondere:

> [...] und [wenn/]falls ich Ihre Hilfe brauchen werde, dann ich werde mich bei Ihnen melden.

klingt in meinen Ohren nach einer Zurückweisung. Ich würde daher darauf verzichten. Insbesondere, da der Verkäufer in "seinem" Laden das Hausrecht hat, und es daher doch eher unhöflich ist, ihn aufzufordern, sich zurückzuziehen, bis er gerufen wird.

Comment: _[...] und [wenn/]falls ich Ihre Hilfe brauchen werde, dann ich werde mich bei Ihnen melden._ würde ich so nie im Alltag sagen. Das ist viel zu lange. Ich sag normalerweise _"falls ich Hilfe brauche/ Fragen habe, melde ich mich"._

Comment: Ja, ein einfacher, kurzer Satz genügt und ist im Zweifelsfall am besten. Ich würde sagen: "Ich will mich nur umschauen."